# Error while trying to obtain information from source and destination in table RSBASIDOC

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, package, sap-bw

There is a package which is used to extract data from SAP systems to SQL, but we are getting the below error while running the package.

> Error while trying to obtain information from source and destination in table RSBASIDOC

But I was not able to understand why I got this error and reason too.
Help me address the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Full log:

```
7/5/2021 2:04:43 PM Data Flow Task BW -> SQL Error 
          XtractKernel.Extractors.XtractException Errors occurred 
          during extraction 
          at XtractIS.XtractSourceDeltaQ.PrimeOutput(lnt32 
          outputs, Int32[] outputlDs. PipelineBuffer[] buffers) 
          at 
          Microsoft SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost 
          .HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper 100 
          Wrapper. Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs.IDTSBuffer100[] 
          buffers, IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)

7/5/2021 2:04:43 PM Data Flow Task BW -> SQL:Error: [2021-07- 
          05T14:04:43.336+02:00]
          XtractKernel Extractors.XtractException: Error while trying 
          to obtain information about source and destination in table 
          RSBASIDOC. This is an indication that the customizing in 
          SAP is not done property. --->
          XtractKernel.Extractors.XtractException: Found != 1 rows 
          in table RSBASIDOC 
          at 
          XtractKernel.Extractors.DeltaQDefinition.GetSystem.Param 
          eters(R3Connection connection) 
          --- End Of inner exception stack trace ---
          XtractKernel.Extractors.DeltaQDefinition.GetSystemParam 
          eters(R3Connection connection) 
          at XtractKernel.Extractors.DeltaQExtractor.Extract() 
          at XtractKernel.Extractors.ExtractorBase`1.Extract 
          (ProcessResultCallback processResult, LoggerBase 
          logger) 
          at XtractIS.XtractSourceDeltaQ.PrimeOutput(lnt32 
          outputs, Int32[] outputlDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)
```

Comment: Please, don't post [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) if you don't really need.